# getting color off calendar in microsoft graph api in calendarview

Tags: colors, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the calendarview in the microsoft graph api, using the following url: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/'+calendarId+'/calendarView?$select=subject,bodyPreview,start,end,location,isAllDay,lastModifiedDateTime,iCalUId,categories](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/%27+calendarId+%27/calendarView?$select=subject,bodyPreview,start,end,location,isAllDay,lastModifiedDateTime,iCalUId,categories)

Everything works, I get the data I need, but I would at the same time like to get the color and hexcolor of the calendar, but I am not sure how to do that, so I hope someone else can help with it,

I tried adding ,calendar to the $select part but without it giving me anything back about the calendar these events belong to.

I see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0 that I should be able to do it if I understand this correct, so I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CalendarView will only ever return event objects (or the underlying calendar items in Exchange). The Calendar color property only exists on the Calendar and is not a property of the events themselves. With your request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/'+calendarId+'/calendarView?$select=subject,bodyPreview,start,end,location,isAllDay,lastModifiedDateTime,iCalUId,categories
```

This will only return events from the calendar with the calendarId your passing in so if you want the calendar color you just need to make a separate request on the calendar endpoint eg a Get to

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/'+calendarId+](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/%27+calendarId+)

Comment: Okay thanks, had hoped there was something I overlooked, as it would have been sweet to see the colors at this level too, I accepted your answer :)